# how to convert this typescript code to javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
export interface VideoPlayerProps {
  videoTrack: ILocalVideoTrack | IRemoteVideoTrack | undefined;
  audioTrack: ILocalAudioTrack | IRemoteAudioTrack | undefined;
}
const MediaPlayer = (props: VideoPlayerProps) => {
   const container = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
   useEffect(() => {
     if (!container.current) return;
     props.videoTrack?.play(container.current);
     return () => {
      props.videoTrack?.stop();
     };
  }, [container, props.videoTrack]);
}
```

The above code is in Typescript (I guess) and I want to convert this to Js for using it in ReactJs.
I can't understand how the props are defined here can someone please help to define them in ReactJs JavaScript?

Comment: Delete the interface completely, and remove `: VideoPlayerProps`. Neither of those are used in JS

Comment: But what are these " videoTrack: ILocalVideoTrack | IRemoteVideoTrack | undefined; " values assigned to videoTrack?

Comment: Why not use https://www.typescriptlang.org/play to convert it?

Comment: And also use simply `useRef(null)`

Comment: @Anonymousss Those aren't values. Those are types. And javascript don't have types like that so they mean nothing in javascript. They only have meaning in typescript

Comment: @slebetman those question marks in "props.videoTrack?.play()" are also useless in js?

Comment: No. Those exist in javascript. It's a javascript feature, not a typescript feature. Typescript will simply leave them in the generated javascript source when compiled. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 0):

```
    const MediaPlayer = (props) => {
       const {videoTrack,audioTrack} = props;
       const container = useRef(null);
       useEffect(() => {
         if (!container.current) return;
         videoTrack?.play(container.current);
         return () => {
          videoTrack?.stop();
         };
      }, [container, videoTrack]);
    }
    export default MediaPlayer;
```